# Unable to connect to MySQL server from MySQL Workbench using ssh connection

Tags: mysql, ssh

This is my first posting to stackoverflow, and I have searched the forum but could not find any answer. I am brand new at setting up a MySQL server, a ssh connection to a MySQL server, and MySQL Workbench. There are 3 Windows PCs running Workbench CE (version 6.3), and one Ubuntu Linux PC running MySQL CE. The server and PCs are on a home network.  The server’s ip address is 192.168.1.215; the PCs ip addresses are dynamic.  Every PC receives the identical error message.  The MySQL server is setup on a Linux Ubuntu server. I can log into MySQL from Windows using Putty from the Windows PCs.

In Workbench I setup the port address 3306 for the server. I received this error message when trying to connect to the MySQL server using MySQL Workbench

```
Could not connect the SSH Tunnel 
Authentication error, unhandled exception caught in in 
tunnel manager, please refer to logs for details
```

I found the log file, wb.log, on the Windows PC. The wb.log is over 100 lines, and I have enclosed the last 25 lines, which show the error message.

```
10:34:12 [INF][ WBContext]: System info: 
MySQL Workbench Community (GPL) for Windows version 6.3.4 revision 0 build 828 (64 bit) 
Configuration Directory: C:\Users\Daddio\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench 
Data Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE 
Cairo Version: 1.10.2 
OS: Microsoft Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 
CPU: 8x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz, 32.0 GiB RAM 
Active video adapter ATI Radeon HD 4800 Series 
Installed video RAM: 1024 MB 
Current video mode: 1280 x 1024 x 4294967296 colors 
Used bit depth: 32 
Driver version: 8.920.0.0 
Installed display drivers: 
aticfx64.dll,aticfx64.dll,aticfx32,aticfx32,atiumd64.dll,atidxx64.dll,atiumdag,atidxx32,atiumdva,atiumd6a.cap,atitmm64.dll 
Current user language: English (United States) 

10:34:12 [INF][ Workbench]: UI is up 
10:34:12 [INF][ Workbench]: Running the application 
10:34:14 [INF][ SSH tunnel]: Starting tunnel 
10:34:14 [INF][ SSH tunnel]: Existing SSH tunnel not found, opening new one 
10:35:55 [INF][ SSH tunnel]: Opening SSH tunnel to 192.168.1.215:3306 
10:35:55 [WRN][sshtunnel.py:_connect_ssh:288]: IOError, probably caused by file C:\Users\Daddio\AppData\Roaming\MySQL\Workbench\ssh\known_hosts not found, the message was: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\Users\\Daddio\\AppData\\Roaming\\MySQL\\Workbench\\ssh\\known_hosts' 
10:35:55 [ERR][sshtunnel.py:notify_exception_error:233]: Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\sshtunnel.py", line 298, in _connect_ssh 
look_for_keys=has_key, allow_agent=has_key) 
File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE/python/site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 301, in connect 
t.start_client() 
File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE/python/site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 461, in start_client 
raise e 
SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner[Errno 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine 

10:35:56 [INF][ SSH tunnel]: TunnelManager.wait_connection authentication error: Authentication error, unhandled exception caught in tunnel manager, please refer to logs for details 
10:35:56 [ERR][ SSH tunnel]: Authentication error opening SSH tunnel: Authentication error, unhandled exception caught in tunnel manager, please refer to logs for details 
10:37:26 [INF][ WBContext]: Connection to LINUXSERVER cancelled by user: Tunnel connection cancelled 
10:37:29 [INF][ Workbench]: Shutting down Workbench 
10:37:29 [INF][ mforms managed]: Shutting down mforms wrapper 
10:37:29 [INF][ Workbench]: Done
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Ubuntu, you may need to manually update your version of MySQL Workbench. This is a bug in version 6.0.8 which is currently the one in Ubuntu repositories. Updating to version 6.3.6 fixed this for me.

Downloads here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/#downloads

Comment: Yes. go ahead and make sure you have at least 6.3 version of MySQL workbench. otherwise you will be debugging for a while, there is bug in ssh tunneling in 6.2 version I faced

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this problem when i update mysql-workbench. What you need to do is to upgrade paramiko through pip.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install paramiko
```

This will install crypto package that use ssh tunnel.

Answer (score -1):

How I solved it in Windows 7:

1. Open C:/Users/User/.ssh/known_hosts (or how your system is set up)
2. Find the line: 192.168.1.215 sh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAA....
3. Remove the whole section (make sure you don't erase other stored hosts)
4. Try connecting again with MySQL Workbench

I hope this would help :) Because I spent hours trying to dig this out.

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Unfortunately, the known_hosts does file not contain the line: 192.168.1.215 sh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAA....   There are 4 lines starting with:  192.30.252.131, 192.30.252.129, 192.30.252.130, and 192.30.252.128.  So, there is nothing to remove.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue by downgrading python-crypto package in ubuntu 16.04.
Rollback version 2.6.1-6ubuntu0.16.04.2 to 2.6.1-6build1 using below command.

```
sudo apt-get install  python-crypto=2.6.1-6build1
```